# Google Chrome - cannot submit few times same form using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome

I'm preparing wrapper form, which later sends my query to other forms. In my script I'm changing form action and name of input field in which query is stored. Then I'm sending multiple times prepared form using `.submit()`. In **FF** and **IE** it works. In **Google Chrome** I noticed a problem - form is send only once. Only last call is executed.

Is there any way to force it to work also in **Google Chrome**?

Please take a look at following code (again - problem exists only in **Google Chrome**):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function formSubmit()
{
document.getElementById("frm1").target="_blank";    
document.getElementById("frm1").action="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/form_action.asp";

document.getElementById("frm1").fname.value = '1111';
document.getElementById("frm1").submit();

document.getElementById("frm1").action="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/form_action.asp?salt=1";

document.getElementById("frm1").fname.value = '2222';
document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Enter some text in the field below, then press the "Submit" button to submit the form.</p>

<form name="frm1" id="frm1" method="get">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" onclick="formSubmit()" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Used browsers:

- Google Chrome: `18.0.1025.142`
- Firefox: `11.0`
- Internet Explorer: `8.0.6001.18702`

Comment: Oh and also [please consider using another source of information about web programming](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: Hmm ... your first post is to a new window; that's somewhat fishy now that I think about it.

Comment: [Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/6MvE6/)  I'm pretty sure I'd call this a bug in Chrome, unless there's some spec that says that after a normal post of a `<form>`, whether or not there's a "target", the form cannot be submitted again.

Comment: You are right, that's fishy indeed.

Comment: Set up a fiddle using your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/a98ka/. I am unable to duplicate the issue using Chrome (version 16.0.912.77 m)

Comment: I am also unable to duplicate the issue after I updated to Chrome 18.0.1025.142 m

Comment: @pete: So two new tabs are opened when you are submitting this form?

Comment: @petee I misunderstood what you were asking. I am able to duplicate the error after all.

Comment: OK - issue is reported as [121869](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121869).